# unable to pick gallery image to imagebutton?

Tags: android

I'm getting the gallery intent but not able to set image on Image-Button although i have given the required permissions.

```
imagg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            gallery.setType("image/=");
            startActivityForResult(gallery, res);
        }
    });

     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == res && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageurl = data.getData();
        imagg.setImageURI(imageurl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imagg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

gallery.setType("image/*");
gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery,"Select Picture"), 1);
        }
    });

     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == res && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageurl = data.getData();
         String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: code working fine with no errors but app is gettting crashed after picking the image from gallery.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri Image = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = null;
            try {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Image);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap SelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(SelectedImage);

       }
    }